# Share iOS app crash report with developer

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, flurry

My boss has an individual Apple developer program. Normally when there are error in his apps, he would just tell me the errors, but lately the errors are too many, so now he just sent me the crash report from Flurry.
The thing is, it is not symbolicated. And when I tried to symbolicate it in my computer, the app is not the same archive with the one sent to Apple, so I didn't get anything. And this also poses a problem when there are many archives.

This symbolicate process is confusing to me. Is there an easy way to find the errors and symbolicate it using my XCode for the apps published using my boss' XCode?

Using flurry or any other way (Apple's own Crash report?)

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can pass a core dump to get your hands on it to debug, but there are several tools can help gather the crash report for you.

I am using Crashlytics to collect the crash report, and it will send you email to let you know a new crash happened or a regression, beatiful UI design and already decoded the symbols for you. It's very easy to setup and absorb. Just check it out.

Crashlytics is bundled with Fabric, including many new features you may need in the future.

Apple recently announced its own crash reporting tool, you could also consider. But I am still stick to Crashlytics since there is no reason not to...

If you know the trick, you can decode the symbols on your own, just search how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend crashlytics of fabric.io.